# How to manage masks?

Tags: ios, mask

I have issues in my UI understanding masks. In some cases, the zone I can tap on is smaller than the zone I can see. If I use

```
myView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

I can then see only the zone I can tap on. But I don't understand why it's doing this, neither how to increase my touchable zone. I've tried with some

```
myView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleSometing
```

but as I don't know how it works, the results isn't satisfying.

Can anyone help me understand how to manage these masks ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

those are 2 different things.

[image]

**clipsToBounds** means  if you have a view2 in view1, by default you can see like above

but if you set *view1.clipsToBounds = YES* , all the presentation in view1 will be clipped in the region of the view1's bound like below

Document says : 
Setting this value to YES causes subviews to be clipped to the bounds of the receiver. If set to NO, subviews whose frames extend beyond the visible bounds of the receiver are not clipped. The default value is NO.

[image]

**autoresizingMask** means the way to resize the view's frame when the superView's frame changed

Document says : When a view’s bounds change, that view automatically resizes its subviews according to each subview’s autoresizing mask. You specify the value of this mask by combining the constants described in UIViewAutoresizing using the C bitwise OR operator. Combining these constants lets you specify which dimensions of the view should grow or shrink relative to the superview. The default value of this property is UIViewAutoresizingNone, which indicates that the view should not be resized at all.

[image]

Comment: Ok, so in my case I have view2 in view1, but the touchable zone is view1's. Right ? Is there a way to fit automatically view1's frame to its content ?